# Electron main.ts cannot use import outside a module

Tags: typescript, electron, package.json

In `tsconig`  I have

```
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true
```

In `package.json` I have

```
  "type": "module",
  "private": true,
  "main": "public/main.ts",
```

and in `main.ts` I have

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog } from "electron";
// do other stuff
```

When I run my electron app I get this error:

```
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, dialog } from "electron";
^^^^^^
Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

I have set the module to commonjs in my pakcage.json but its still not happy with it.

Comment: Try with `require` instead of `import` on main.